# What does dipping my head in wax do?

Tags: dark-souls-3

So I'm in the Grand Archives, and I came across a pool of wax I can dunk my head into. When I do so, I get a nice fancy looking head covered in wax.

[image]

So, that looks pretty fancy and all, but what exactly does this do?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The waxed head  will make you immune to the damage and curses those Ghost Hands inflict, as seen below. The buff only lasts for a few minutes, but there's a couple pools spread throughout the grand archives, so you don't need to always run back to that one to reapply the buff.

[image]